# Show that $a^{13} \equiv a \pmod{3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

> Show that $a^{13} \equiv a \pmod{3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13}$.

I want to know if my attempt is correct.

First $a^{13} \equiv (a^3)^4 \cdot a \equiv a^4 \cdot a \equiv a^3 \cdot a^2 \equiv a \cdot a^2 \equiv a^3 \equiv a \pmod 3$.

Second, $(a^7)^2 \cdot a^{-1} \equiv a^2 \cdot a^{-1} \equiv a \pmod 7$.

Third, $a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \implies a^{13} \equiv a \pmod{13}$.

So, $3, 7, 13 | a^{13} - a$. Since they are relatively prime in pairs, $$3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 | a^{13} - a \implies a^{13} \equiv a \pmod{ 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13}$$

Is it correct? Could you suggest an easier or a better proof?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That looks good. If you want to be picky, then for $a=7$ you cannot use $a^{-1}$ in deriving $a^{13}=a\bmod 7$. Similarly $a^{13}=a\bmod 13$ is true for all $a$, but $a^{12}=1\bmod13$ is not true for $a=13$.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime, then $a^p\equiv a \pmod p$ for every $a\in\mathbb{Z}$; repeatedly multiplying this congruence by $a^{p-1}$ it follows that $a^{k(p-1)+1}\equiv a \pmod p$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. So you have directly $a^{6\cdot 2+1}\equiv a \pmod 3$, $a^{2\cdot 6+1}\equiv a \pmod 7$, and $a^{12+1}\equiv a \pmod{13}$. Then you conclude the reasoning as in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euler's Theorem (or you may even use Fermat's theorem),

$a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {3} \implies a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies a^{13} \equiv a \pmod 3$

$a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod {7} \implies a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \implies a^{13} \equiv a \pmod 7$

$a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod {13} \implies a^{13} \equiv a \pmod {13} $

$\therefore a^{13} \equiv a \pmod {lcm[3,7,13]} \implies a^{13} \equiv a \pmod {3\times7\times13}$

It is quit trivial if $a$ is not co-prime to at least one of $3, 7, 13.$ Then you will not even need Euler or Fermat's theorem.

> Remember, if
>
> $a\equiv b \pmod {m_1}$
>
> $a\equiv b \pmod {m_2}$
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> $a\equiv b \pmod {m_n}$
>
> then, $a\equiv b \pmod {lcm[m_1,m_2,...,m_n]}$

Comment: Thanks. That was a great hint about the LCM. I didn't know that. Do you have any idea how I can prove that?

Comment: @Dhruv Take an example and see how it works....

Comment: @Dhruv Use the example $8\equiv 2 \pmod x$ and find all $x$.You will understand it ...

Answer (score 0):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, we have that $ R = \mathbb{Z}/(3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13)\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z} $, so the equation $ X^{13} - X = 0 $ holds for $ R $ if it holds for each factor ring on the right. On the other hand, we know by Fermat's little theorem that this equation does hold for each ring on the right, and the result follows. (Note that $ 2, 6 | 12 $, which is why the equation holds.)